# Magento custom Shipping module description not showing on email template

Tags: magento

I have created a custom shipping method to show depo-names from which customers will pickup the products,

So everything goes fine from storing and retrieving depo details in frontend/backend on order view pages by adding a overwrite model file

**Added this in config.xml**

```
  <models>

            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Module_Model_Sales_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
    </models>
```

**Added Order.php with**

```
<?php
class Module_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order{
    public function getShippingDescription(){
        $desc = parent::getShippingDescription();
        $desc = $desc." added the shipping depo details from order id"; 
        return $desc;
    }
}
```

It did added the shipping description in admin sales view/frontend customer sales views. But its not sending the same shipping description in email template(app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new.html) under

```
 {{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
```

Should i do anything particular for mail template shipping description alone? can someone help me in fixing this?

Comment: Just a hunch, and probably not the answer you need, but did you happen to place the order from the backend? Possibly getShippingDescription relies on an incorrect store id?

Comment: Hi @pspahn, no orders are placed from frontend only.

Comment: @Ela how you add a separate block for shipping description. I have the same issue, I want to filter some shipping methods name and want to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass variable to email templates. Get reference from Excellence Tutorial

- [Advanced Tracsactional Email Templates](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates)

Comment: Thanks i did by adding a separate block file , and i see the same logics here. Thanks for the share.